# Compilation Error in if condition in Java

Tags: java

Trying to compare 2 Integer values but getting a compilation error
"The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) Integer, Integer" in
if (s2.peek() < tempNode.data) statement

There is no compilation error
If I am using == operator
or 
If I remove  type from Node means simply use Node 
not Node

```
private Deque<Integer> s2 = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();

private static class Node<Integer> {
    private Integer data;
    private Node<Integer> nextNode;

    public Node(Integer data, Node<Integer> nextNode) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }
}

public void push(Integer data) {
    Node<Integer> tempNode = new Node<>(data, null);

    if (top == null) {
        top = tempNode;
        s2.push(top.data);
    } else {
        if (s2.peek() < tempNode.data) {

        } else {
            s2.push(s2.peek());
        }

        tempNode.nextNode = top;
        top = tempNode;
    }
}
```

There should be no compilation error as both data are of Integer types.

Answer (score 3):

Your class `Node` is incorrectly defined in

```
private static class Node<Integer> {
    private Integer data;
    private Node<Integer> nextNode;

    public Node(Integer data, Node<Integer> nextNode) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }
}
```

you have created a generic type `Integer`. It should be

```
private static class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> nextNode;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> nextNode) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean to say in Java I can't define the type as Integer, I have to use Generics like <T>

Comment: @AtishayJain You can name the generic **anything**; but if you name it `Integer` then it *masks* `java.lang.Integer`. Name it `<Bob>` if you want (but `<T>` is one of the "standard" names).

Comment: The “official” java *convention* is to use single capital letters as the names of types, `T` (an abbreviation of “Type”) being the most common.